# Google map api search markers from database in specifc area

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've set up google map API that loads data from mysql database and display markers. the problem I am facing is that all the markers shows up at once no matter whatever I input in search location field..............   **I want to show only the searched area and markers in that area. It shouldn't display  all the markers at once but only the marker in the searched area.**

I mean I want to zoom the map to the searched area. Currently if I've only one marker map zoom in to show that but if I've many markers the map zoom out to show all the markers. Here is the map I'm working on "http://funfeat.com/clients/gmap/gmap3.html" NOW I've set markers very very far and the map is still showing all the markers by zooming out.

The gmap.php is the file that provide xml results from mysql database. and the below code is what I am using to display map

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <title>Google Maps AJAX + mySQL/PHP Example</title>
    <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"
            type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infoWindow;
    var locationSelect;

    function load() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(40, -100),
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap',
        mapTypeControlOptions: {style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DROPDOWN_MENU}
      });
      infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

      locationSelect = document.getElementById("locationSelect");
      locationSelect.onchange = function() {
        var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
        if (markerNum != "none"){
          google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
        }
      };
   }

   function searchLocations() {
     var address = document.getElementById("addressInput").value;
     var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
     geocoder.geocode({address: address}, function(results, status) {
       if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        searchLocationsNear(results[0].geometry.location);
       } else {
         alert(address + ' not found');
       }
     });
   }

   function clearLocations() {
     infoWindow.close();
     for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
       markers[i].setMap(null);
     }
     markers.length = 0;

     locationSelect.innerHTML = "";
     var option = document.createElement("option");
     option.value = "none";
     option.innerHTML = "See all results:";
     locationSelect.appendChild(option);
   }

   function searchLocationsNear(center) {
     clearLocations();

     var radius = document.getElementById('radiusSelect').value;
     var searchUrl = 'gmap.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;
     downloadUrl(searchUrl, function(data) {
       var xml = parseXml(data);
       var markerNodes = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
       var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
       for (var i = 0; i < markerNodes.length; i++) {
         var name = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("name");
         var address = markerNodes[i].getAttribute("address");
         var distance = parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("distance"));
         var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markerNodes[i].getAttribute("lng")));

         createOption(name, distance, i);
         createMarker(latlng, name, address);
         bounds.extend(latlng);
       }
       map.fitBounds(bounds);
       locationSelect.style.visibility = "visible";
       locationSelect.onchange = function() {
         var markerNum = locationSelect.options[locationSelect.selectedIndex].value;
         google.maps.event.trigger(markers[markerNum], 'click');
       };
      });
    }

    function createMarker(latlng, name, address) {
      var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        position: latlng
      });
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
      markers.push(marker);
    }

    function createOption(name, distance, num) {
      var option = document.createElement("option");
      option.value = num;
      option.innerHTML = name + "(" + distance.toFixed(1) + ")";
      locationSelect.appendChild(option);
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request.responseText, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function parseXml(str) {
      if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        var doc = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLDOM');
        doc.loadXML(str);
        return doc;
      } else if (window.DOMParser) {
        return (new DOMParser).parseFromString(str, 'text/xml');
      }
    }

    function doNothing() {}

    //]]>
  </script>
  </head>

  <body style="margin:0px; padding:0px;" onLoad="load()">
    <div>
     <input type="text" id="addressInput" size="10"/>
    <select id="radiusSelect">
      <option value="25" selected>25mi</option>
      <option value="100">100mi</option>
      <option value="200">200mi</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" onClick="searchLocations()" value="Search"/>
    </div>
    <div><select id="locationSelect" style="width:100%;visibility:hidden"></select></div>
    <div id="map" style="width: 100%; height: 80%"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`http://funfeat.com/clients/gmap/gmap.php?lat=47&lng=-122&radius=2` produces valid XML but your query must be wrong .It pulls out 10 markers, 9 of which are correct but the 10th produces `<marker name="Pakistan" address="Chowk Azam, Layyah" lat="31.008364" lng="71.224342" type="cITY"/>` which is certainly not within 2 miles of the coordinates. Your query should not pick up the last marker from the database.

As the use of  mysql_ functions are discouraged the following code uses PDO can be used

```
//dependant on your setup
$host= "WWW";
$username="XXX";
$password="YYY";
$database="ZZZ";
// Get parameters from URL
$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];
$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];
$radius = $_GET["radius"];

// Start XML file, create parent node
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0");
$node = $dom->createElement("markers");
$parnode = $dom->appendChild($node);
//Connect to database
$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$host;dbname=$database", $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
try {
    // Prepare statement
    $stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT  name, lat, lng, ( 3959 * acos( cos( radians(?) ) * cos( radians( lat ) ) * cos( radians( lng ) - radians(?) ) + sin( radians(?) ) * sin( radians( lat ) ) ) ) AS distance FROM gbstn HAVING distance < ? ORDER BY distance ASC LIMIT 0 , 20");
    // Assign parameters
    $stmt->bindParam(1,$center_lat);
    $stmt->bindParam(2,$center_lng);
    $stmt->bindParam(3,$center_lat);
    $stmt->bindParam(4,$radius);
    //Execute query
    $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();
```

**EDIT** Added to catch error if no records found

```
    if ($stmt->rowCount()==0) {
    $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
    $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
    $newnode->setAttribute("name", "No Records Found");
    $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $center_lat);//Sends marker to search location 
    $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $center_lng);
    $newnode->setAttribute("distance", 0);
            } 
   else {
```

**End of EDIT**

```
    // Iterate through the rows, adding XML nodes for each
    while($row = $stmt->fetch()) {
        $node = $dom->createElement("marker");
        $newnode = $parnode->appendChild($node);
        $newnode->setAttribute("name", $row['name']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("address", $row['address']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lat", $row['lat']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("lng", $row['lng']);
        $newnode->setAttribute("distance", $row['distance']);
        }
    }
echo $dom->saveXML();

}


catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", gmap.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
 }
//Close the connection
$dbh = null;
```

The part of the query above  `HAVING distance < '%s'` is the part that should weed out the last marker.

I have added Error catch if no records are found in search and Map sent to lat/lng 0,0. See [**My Implementation Here**](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php)

Comment: Hello, Here is what I have is gmap.php

 `$query = "SELECT * FROM markers WHERE 1";` 
 This query clearly doesn't depend on parameters provided in url. also there doesn't exists anything in gmap.php that obtains the info from url using `$_GET`. I thought the searched terms were used by the javascripts etc. to zoom and only show the searched area and markers. And skip other markers that are fetched from the database..

So should I try the code you provided and make the search form to send the info as $_get to gmap.php(which will have the code you provided above) ?

Comment: I have changed the code in the answer as the wrong version was sent. Line `var searchUrl = 'gmap.php?lat=' + center.lat() + '&lng=' + center.lng() + '&radius=' + radius;` sends the parameters to `gmap.php` using GET. In my code `$center_lat = $_GET["lat"];$center_lng = $_GET["lng"];$radius = $_GET["radius"];` gets these and is used in query

Comment: Great Job  David,
There was little problem with last few lines of code, I somehow played and made it work.... I am unable to post the full code here.... so you can update your answer... It is just rearranged a bit....
`catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "I'm sorry I'm afraid you can't do that.". $e->getMessage() ;// Remove or modify after testing 
    file_put_contents('PDOErrors.txt',date('[Y-m-d H:i:s]').", mapSelect.php, ". $e->getMessage()."\r\n", FILE_APPEND);  
   }
 
 echo $dom->saveXML();
 

//Close the connection
$dbh = null; 


?>`

Comment: I might have not fixed it properly, but surely you can... As this doesn't echo the xml page. But works on map.... This is the error your code was giving....
`unexpected T_ECHO, expecting T_CATCH` line 42 the new link of working map is http://upocketmoney.com/www.funfeat.com/clients/gmap/gmap3.html

Comment: There is still a little problem with map,.... If there is only one marker in searched location then it map is 100% zoomed in (that shows nothing.) You can try searching `Layyah` and `seattle`on my map, http://upocketmoney.com/www.funfeat.com/clients/gmap/gmap3.html 

And if there is no marker found in searched area the map leads to somewhere in middle north pacific ocean :P and shows no error.

Comment: The catch block only displays PDO errors and sends error code to `PDOErrors.txt`, `mapSelect.php`is the name of the file producing error which you should change to `gmap.php`(see edit to answer). To the second part I have a fix which you can see in [Demo](http://daviestrachan.co.uk/maps/stationmap8a.php) I will edit Answer to show

Comment: @user1831458 Answer updated See my link source code to see how I changed marker for not found

Comment: I'll be very glad if you can give me a good suggestion,..Now I don't have latitude and longitude in database instead I just have addresses, And I've to show markers by using addresses,... I've found a funtion that converts the address into lat and lng. But problem is mysql query you provided is based on lat and lng(i.e it calculates that which markers to select using lat and lng from db) the solution I consider is to select all the markers from and db and then convert all addresses into lat & lng and then refine which markers to show using lat & lng.. Any Idea if there is proper way for this??

Comment: This is the function I found,...
 `var address = "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain  View";
geocoder.getLatLng(address, function(point) {
         var latitude = point.y;
         var longitude = point.x;  

         // do something with the lat lng
    });`

Comment: I would suggest you geocode all your addresses once  and store them in your database.