# google maps - best way to show all saved locations on map (saved in my db or directly on maps server?)

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a page where latitude, longitude can be saved by clicking on the map. Currently storing those values in my db.

I want to build a webpage where I want to show all saved places.

One answer I know is: retrive all records from db, and mark them on map.
This way  also helps in filtering based on some fields in db. By the way, how to show radially, I mean, instead of loading all places at once, I think its good to do ajax requests to my db for places(lat, longitudes) available in that radial region showed by map, when we move the map, then we search in our db for places in that radial range and show only those places. this way, we need not load all(may be a million) saved places at a time. But how to do this? How can I fetch all records in my db whose lat, longitutes present in that radial range?

Another way: While saving in db itself, also save on map somehow so when that map is shown it will simply show that map which automatically shows saved places(saved in google maps server somehow).
Is this possible? even if possible, I think I cant filter(easily) based on fields in this way as they are shown directly by map.  But, if possible to do, it can be used to show simply when not filtering.

Comment: Your question may be closed as it does not fit the guidelines here.See my answer [**HERE**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13551228/google-map-api-search-markers-from-database-in-specifc-area/13551596#13551596) for searching  within a radius. This may help.

Comment: Wow, thanks, +1 for ur answer.