# Update markers on google map

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I want to do the following  , I have say a server where it updates (adds/removes) "Locations" of markers , then when some one uses my app I want him to see the markers available, the question is ... what is the best way to deal with the updating thing ? I mean I don't want the app to redraw all the markers when 1 marker is removed and/or added because I might be having A LOT OF MARKERS and this would take some time when we are talking on real time basis

Comment: similar to that question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20592622/google-maps-best-way-to-show-all-saved-locations-on-map-saved-in-my-db-or-dir

Answer (score 0):

You could store a unique identifier in the database for each marker that gets set as the marker 'snippet' when it is created. By keeping a reference to the Collection of markers in the view you could then update the marker collection (searching for the snippet ID) based on the state of the database, removing or adding from the map as necessary. This would avoid recreating all markers again.